# Why does the size of a Rich Text field change between reading and editing?

Tags: lotus-notes

I created an audit function in the PostSave event of a Form.  When the document is saved, for plain text fields, I compare the contents of the fields before and after a save and if there's been a change, I prompt for the reason.  But for RichText fields I decided instead to capture the number of characters before and after a save.  To get that, I do Len(RTItem.text) in QueryOpen and then again in PostSave.  My assumption was that if the field was modified, the sizes would be different.  However, what I found was that if I edit the document, don't make any changes to any field, when I save I get prompted because the value of "Len(RTItem.text)" is different even tho nothing's been changed.  The difference in pretty small.  In one case it was an 8 character difference.  Any ideas why this is happening?  Any other ideas on auditing a RT field?

thanks
clem

Comment: One explanation could simply be that different versions of Notes will likely have minor differences in the way they translate the editor's rich text data structures to the back-end CD records. If that's not the issue, then the best way to answer this question would probably be to use NotesPeek before and after to look at the representation of the contents of the RT field, comparing what you find in the CD records. I would actually be a bit surprised if you find a predictable pattern to what changes and is added each time, though.

Comment: To do this level of audit tracking you need to look at third party tools like the Midas Rich Text LSX or convert the RT to DXL and compare that content.

Comment: I really didn't want to do a full text comparison.  So I thought simply comparing the number of characters before and after would not only work but be way faster.  But I ran into this problem.